# MATLAB: Differences between .mat versions

Tags: matlab, hdf5, mat-file

The [official documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_version) states the following:

[image]. But I have noticed that there are other important differences besides those stated in the table above.

For example, saving a cell array with about 6,000 elements that occupies **176 MB** of memory in MATLAB gives me the following results depending on whether I use **-v7** or **-v7.3**:

- With **-v7**: File size = **15 MB**, and save & load is **fast**.
- With **-v7.3**: File size = **400 MB**, and save & load is *very* **slow** (probably in part because of the large file size).

Has anybody else noticed these differences?

**Update 1**: As the replies point out, **-v7.3** relies on HDF5 and according to Mathworks, *"this format has a significant storage overhead"*, although it's not clear if this overhead is really due to the format itself, or to the MATLAB implementation and handling of HDF5 instead.

**Update 2**: @Andrew Janke points us to [this very helpful PDF](http://mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf) (which apparently is not available in HTML format on the web). For more details, see the comments in the answer provided by @Amro.

This all takes me to the next question: **Are there any alternatives** that combine the best of both worlds (e.g. the efficiency of **-v7** and the ability to deal with very large files of -**v7.3**)?

Comment: Those interested, check out this recent article: [Improving save performance](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/improving-save-performance/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Version 7.3 of MAT-files uses HDF5 format, this format has a significant storage overhead to describe the contents of the file, especially so for complex nested cellarrays and structures. Its main advantage over previous versions of MAT-files is that it allows storing data larger than 2GB on 64-bit systems.

Note that both v7 and v7.3 are compressed and use Unicode encoding (unlike v6), yet they are two completely different formats...

*References:*

- [MAT-File Preferences](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/preferences.html#brjh09y-7)
- [MAT-File Versions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html)

Comment: Thanks @Amro. I'm intrigued by the fact that "significant storage overhead" means that we need 400 MB instead of 15 MB for the exact same data, but I guess that explains everything.

Comment: @AmV: the thing with cell and structure arrays is that they can store heterogeneous data types, and each type needs to be "described". If you compare the two formats (v7/v7.3) using a regular MATLAB "double" matrix (ex: `M = rand(3000,3000); save v7.mat M -v7; save v73.mat M -v7.3`), you would get similar file sizes. On the other hand, replace the above matrix with a cell array (`M = num2cell(M);`) and you will see a big difference in size...

Comment: See also http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf for a full description of the MAT file format. Since HDF5 is a general purpose format, some descriptive type info is done with strings in the headers (e.g. "MATLAB_class", "double"). In the MAT format, built-in Matlab types are described with binary magic cookies that fit in a couple bytes, so the MAT headers can be as small as 56 bytes. If you're on Linux or cygwin, "h5dump -p" and "od -c" will give you a view of the headers in the v7.3 files.

Comment: @Andrew, that's a very helpful piece of documentation. I always thought that the PDF documentation was replicated in the [official HTML documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/index.html). Maybe it is? I couldn't find an explanation of the MAT-File format with this level of detail in the HTML doc.

Comment: Thanks AmV. That PDF file is the only place I have seen this info. I don't think it's in the online documentation. MATLAB > User Guide > External interfaces > "Importing and Exporting MAT-files..." is the closest I've seen, and that only discusses the public C and Fortran APIs for it.

Comment: @AndrewJanke that PDF says "level 5". Does that correspond to matlab v6 files?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb there's a bit of overlap with those version numbers but yes, MAT-files level 5 cover the `-v6` and `-v7` save/load flags, while level 4 corresponds to `-v4` flag. Note that HDF5-based MAT-files (`-v7.3` flag) are not discussed in that PDF document. So if you save a MAT-file using either `-v6` or `-v7` flags you actually get the following header at the beginning of the file `MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on: ...`. Using `-v7.3` you get `MATLAB 7.3 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN, Created on: ... HDF5 schema 1.00 .`, while `-v4` doesn't produce any textual header.

Comment: Note that the versions in the save/load flag correspond to MATLAB versions when they were introduced I guess, although it is now more common to name MATLAB by the release number (as in R2016a). You can see the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history) for a mapping between MATLAB versions and their release names. The current documentation of save makes it a bit clearer: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#inputarg_version