# Cannot save really big matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, save, mat-file

I have a big array (1024x1024x360) and I want to save it to a mat file. When I just try

```
A=rand(1024,1024,360)
save('filename.mat','A');
```

The variable is created in the workspace, the file is being created, but it remains empty... 
I'm using Matlab 2012a on Win7-64 machine, Why is that happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Earlier versions of Matlab couldn't save variables larger than 2 GB.  Your default save file format may be set to an older type even on newer versions of Matlab; my own install of R2013a seems to have come preset to v7, which won't save anything that big.  You have two choices:  either specify the format for this file using an extra flag:

```
save('filename.mat','A','-v7.3');
```

or change the default for all save files by running `preferences` and looking in the **MAT-files** area under **General**.

Comment: +1 just be aware that v7.3 is based on HDF5 format unlike previous versions: [MATLAB: Differences between .mat versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950630/matlab-differences-between-mat-versions)