# Saving a large matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab

How to save a cell matrix of size 500K x 110 in Matlab in an efficient and quickest way (if possible).

It has a combination of strings and numerical data.

Traditional Matlab "save" method is failing most likely because the matrix is too big.

I tried hdf5write but this does not work when the data types are different within the same matrix data.

I also tried the suggestion here but this method slows over time
[Cannot save really big matrix in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226803/cannot-save-really-big-matrix-in-matlab)

I also tried these but over time they slow too
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24483-fast-function-to-save-a-matrix

Comment: `whos` of that matrix?

Comment: First of all, don't use cell arrays.

Comment: Here is the Whos - Size: 831493x108, Byte: 10884056934, Type:cell (This is bigger than the 500K x 110 posted above).

Comment: Have you tried the 7.3 format on the save file?

Comment: Yes it was given in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226803/cannot-save-really-big-matrix-in-matlab. I thought of another solution by writing into CSV (this seems faster than inserting into DB) then a dts package to perform a bulk load into SQL table.