# How to save extracted variable or layer from multiple HDF5 files

Tags: matlab

I am trying to extract a specific layer from multiple ( > 4000 ) `HDF5 files`. I used the code below. It worked, but when I tried to load the  new saved files,  they were not recognized as `HDF5`. Help would be highly appreciated.

```
files=dir('C:\OLD_GPM\*.HDF5') % Open  dataset
for j = 1:numel(files)
         r = h5read(files(j).name,'/Grid/precipitationCal');% Read the correct layer "Precipitation calibrated mm/hr"
save([''C:\New_GPM\' files(j).name],'r'); % save this layer
end
```

Comment: You could try enforcing version 7.3 when using `save` (older versions of mat-file don't use hdf5), alternatively try `hdf5write`

Comment: Much appreciation Daniel for the kind reply. I am wondering if it would be possible to just convert the files to .mat files straight away?

Comment: If you want HDF5-based mat-files use `save(['C:\New_GPM\' files(j).name],'r','-v7.3');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Only mat-file version 7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950630/matlab-differences-between-mat-versions) are HDF5 files, all older versions use another format. Use `save(['C:\New_GPM\' files(j).name],'r','-v7.3');` to enforce writing an HDF5 file.