# Matlab: Is it possible to save in the workspace a vector that contains 4 millions of values?

Tags: matlab, vector, save, workspace

I am calculating something and, as result I have a vector 4 millions elements. I am not still finished to calculate it. I´ve calculate it will take 2 and a half hours more. When I will have finished I could save it?
It is not possible, what can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to do? To stop a calculation and continue it later? Otherwise you case use save command (as Ghaul replied).

Comment: I just want to know if a vector with so many elements could be saved by saving the workspace.

Comment: That will of course depend on your computer, but 4 million is not that big, so most modern computers should handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 32-bit you can have at maximum a double array of 155-200 millions of elements. Check other OSs on [Mathworks support page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1110.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the command [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html). If you just need it for later Matlab computations, then it is best to save it in *.mat* format.

```
save('SavedFile.mat','largeVector')
```

You can then load your file whenever you need it using the [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) function.

```
load('SavedFile.mat')
```

Comment: Thank you for writting by I don´t consider this answer as a good answer. This response don´t answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine it takes 0.01 sec to get a random vector with 4 million elements, with [`whos`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/who.html) you can see that it takes (only) 32 MB.

It would take only few seconds to save such amount of data with MATLAB. If you are working with post-R2007b then maybe it is better to save with [`'-v7.3'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) option, newer MATLAB versions use by default general HDF5 format but there [could be some performance/disc usage issues.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949939/matlab-saving-several-variables-to-v7-3-hdf5-mat-files-seems-to-be-faster)